# carrierwave-video error: nil is not a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, carrierwave

I'm using the [carrierwave-video](https://github.com/rheaton/carrierwave-video) gem to upload videos using my Rails app.  When I try to upload a video, I get the following error:

**Failed to transcode with FFmpeg. Check ffmpeg install and verify video is not corrupt or cut short. Original error: nil is not a symbol.**

I believe that my ffmpeg installation was successful because if I can run the following command successfully:

```
qt-faststart input.mp4 output.mp4
```

Looking more closely at my logs, it seems like the parameters for the video file are correct, but I have two rollbacks when the app tries to create a video record:

```
Started POST "/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-27 11:42:04 -0400
Processing by VideosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5lMoFtM5Rrdu4Ra8ut8rD3jYv3FJ0cxo38QW5ATw9ZQ=", "video"=>{"project_id"=>"4", "step_id"=>"22", "saved"=>"true", "embed_url"=>"", "video_path"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f84702436b8 @original_filename="2013-08-02 17.19.02.mp4", @content_type="video/mp4", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video[video_path]\"; filename=\"2013-08-02 17.19.02.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/dc/c0nfvwy96lq7p4ll94mklnmr0000gp/T/RackMultipart20130927-1871-173l2g7>>}, "button"=>""}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "4"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f847058fd08 @base=#<Video id: nil, embed_url: "", project_id: 4, step_id: 22, saved: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, thumbnail_url: nil, image_id: nil, video_path: nil>, @messages={:video_path=>["Failed to transcode with FFmpeg. Check ffmpeg install and verify video is not corrupt or cut short. Original error: nil is not a symbol"]}>
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 616ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Has anyone had a similar problem, and if so, how did you solve it?

**Video.rb:**

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  # maybe we should add a title attribute to the video?
  attr_accessible :position, :project_id, :step_id, :image_id, :saved, :embed_url, :thumbnail_url, :video_path
  mount_uploader :video_path, VideoPathUploader
...
  def set_success(format, opt)
    self.success = true
  end
end
```

**video_path_uploader.rb**

```
class VideoPathUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer

  process encode_video: [:mp4, callbacks: { after_transcode: :set_success } ]

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process thumbnail: [{format: 'png', quality: 10, size: 158, strip: false, logger: Rails.logger}]
    def full_filename for_file
      png_name for_file, version_name
    end
  end

  version :square_thumb do
     process thumbnail: [{format: 'png', quality: 10, size: 105, strip: false, logger: Rails.logger}]
    def full_filename for_file
      png_name for_file, version_name
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: And you've double-checked that your ffmpeg installation is working?

Comment: thanks for your help.  it turned out to be an error with the gem which was resolved in a patch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057754/gem-integrate-change-from-pull-request